# Express with absolute file path?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a directory sitting in dropbox on a different drive. The path is something like:

`T:\Dropbox\Me\Dropbox (Work)\Project - Foo\FILES`

Yet the following gives me a `Cannot Get /` Error when I try to access `http://localhost:4101`:

```
const os = require('os');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const localPath = `T:\\Dropbox\\Me\\Dropbox (Work)\\Project - Foo\\FILES`

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(localPath))

app.listen(4101, () => console.log('Local CDN Started!'))
```

Note that `fs.existsSync(localPath)` is `true`.

How can I set express to properly use the folder in this other directory/drive?

Comment: Do you have `index` file (for example `index.html`) in this path?

Comment: no - does express not generate an index/tree for the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express does not generate a directory listing. But you can use plugin [`serve-index`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index#serve-directory-indexes-with-express):

```
app.use('/ftp', express.static('public/ftp'), serveIndex('public/ftp', {'icons': true}))
```